# String representation of List<String> list

Tags: java, guava

I hava a `List<String>` that I need to serialize or make a String representation.

For example I have:

```
myList.add("Bob");
myList.add("account");
myList.add("userId");
```

The list can contain variable number of items and I need it to be serialized in this form:

```
\Bob\-\account\-\userId\
```

I can do a for loop like:

```
String ss;

for (String s: myList) {
   s = "\\" + s + "\\";
   ss = s + "-";
}
```

However there will be a `"-"` in the tail of the resulting `String ss`

Or is there a Google Guava function to do this already?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can easily use [Apaches Commons StringUtils](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.3/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html):

```
 String ss = "\\" + StringUtils.join(myList.iterator(), "\\-\\") + "\\";
```

Answer (score 7):

Using Guava:

```
String s = Joiner.on('-').join(Iterables.transform(list, new Function<String, String>() {
    @Override
    public String apply(String input) {
        return "\\" + input + "\\";
    }
});
```

Comment: The Christoph's solution seems better, as using transform will product many temporary string, or many compiler-produced garbage StringBuilder

Comment: I agree, performance-wise, but I doubt it really matters. I find my solution more logical, because it better reflects the fact that what is desired is a dash-seperated string of elements surrounded by backslashes.

Comment: +1 for making aware of Guava alternative, but Apache commons lib one looks cleaner

Comment: While it may capture the intention better, it may also be harder to understand and I think it's really an abuse of Guava's functional features. Six lines for what could be easily accomplished in one? That's from the Guava docs: "Excessive use of Guava's functional programming idioms can lead to verbose, confusing, unreadable, and inefficient code. These are by far the most easily (and most commonly) abused parts of Guava, and when you go to preposterous lengths to make your code "a one-liner," the Guava team weeps. [...] Imperative code should be your default, your first choice as of Java 7."

Answer (score 6):

The straight-forward way to solve this using Guava is the [Joiner](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Joiner.html):

```
System.out.println("\\" + Joiner.on("\\-\\").join(myList) + "\\");
```

Comment: Yeah, that's what I'd recommend.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, it is recommended to use StringBuilder during such concatenations.

Secondly, you can use Apache Common Lang's StringUtils.join()` method as follows to achieve the same:

```
ss = "\\" + StringUtils.join(myList.iterator(), "\\-\\") + "\\";
```

Comment: BTW Guava provides a [Joiner](https://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn-history/r13/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Joiner.html) that can do the same as the StringUtils class.

Answer (score 0):

You can fix it by changing your loop like:

```
String ss = "";

for (String s: myList) {
    s = "\\" + s + "\\";
    if(ss.equals("")) {
        ss = s;
    }
    else {
        ss += " - " + s;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the other solutions is an old fashioned for loop which is based on the List size().

The other thing I would do is use a StringBuffer as it is more efficient than concatenating Strings. Internally when you concatenate a String, the object is destroyed and recreated.

```
int myListSize = myList.size();
StringBuffer ss = new StringBuffer(4);
for (int i=0; i < myListSize; i++) {
   ss.append("\\").append(myList.get(i)).append("\\");
   if (i < myListSize - 1) {
      ss.append("-");
   }
}
```

Then to output from a StringBuffer:

```
ss.toString();
```

Personally I think these for loops (as above) end up being easier to read.

Comment: I agree with the other posters who recommend Apache Commons Lang StringUtils. If you don't mind using another library that class is very handy.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest code for string joining that I know goes like this:

```
String sep = "", out = "";
for (String s : myList) {
  out += sep + '\\' + s + '\\';
  sep = "-";
}
```

Comment: Should always use a `StringBuilder` when appending in a loop like that.